# Calculate trend for games

Tags: math, statistics, formula, trend

I have list of games and dataset count play per hour. Dataset count play with blank if no play.

```
[
 {
    gameId: 1,
    plays: [
      { date: "2020-07-19 10:00", count: 5 }, { date: "2020-07-19 13:00", count: 8 }
    ]
 }
]
```

I want show trend games per week/day/month.
Do not forget what exists new games with only start recruit play count.
What formula to use ? where to look ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dataset count play per hour"?

Comment: What do you mean by "Dataset count play with blank if no play."?

Comment: What do you mean by "trend games"?

Comment: What do you mean by "what exists new games with only start recruit play count"?

Comment: If all of those do no happen to be technical terms I just am unaware of, then you will have to explain in more detail. Also, since I have a gut feeling that this might be more about language skills than technicalities, please consider consulting a friend who is more fluent in English, even if clueless in math or statistics. Perfect English is not required on StackOverflow (or I myself would be pretty lost), but in this case I think the clarity and answerability of your question might noticeable improve with a little help on the language. Have fun.

Comment: Your [mre] would probably benefit from having more than one dataset, seeing as you are asking about trends...